# Mac on starting show black screen with folder icon

Tags: macos, startup

[image]

I'm on Macbook Air Macos Sierra

I actually deleted the Recovery HD partition. Although I backed up the recovery files in external. Have MacBackup with Time Machine.I was trying to recover space by removing ubuntu OS partition space which I did successfully. But then I end up messing things in the attempt of increasing Macintosh HD CoreStorage Volume.